# How to resize two windows at the same time in Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager, cinnamon

I find it quite practical the ability to tile windows using <kbd>Super</kbd> + arrow keys in my Linux Mint box (using Cinnamon).

My common use case is to be able to see two windows at the same time, while working only in one of them, like:

```
 _________
|    |    |
| W1 | W2 |
|    |    |
|____|____|
```

Now, what I'd love to be able to do is to resize both windows *at the same time* using the mouse, by dragging the "line" in the middle.

Right now, when I need more screen state in onw window, I have to resize one first and then the other, setting the sizes manually.

How could I do this?

I know there is a [gtiles](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/21) extension, but that's a bit too much for me: it adds two much steps for setting up the tile window, plus you can't resize freely as I'd like to be able to do.

Comment: Btw, for whoever reads this in 2018+, this works as expected in Ubuntu 18.04 w/ GNOME Shell, and I don't remember having to configure anything. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I discovered a sort of a workaround that enables me to do what I want, these are the steps:

1. "snap" a window, by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + arrow key (same behavior as tiling a window, but this time in "snap mode")
2. maximize the other window: it will fit in the space remaining after the "snapped" window
3. resize the snapped window until you're happy

The other window will adapt its to the remaining space when you finish resizing.

Learned after description in this post: http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2013/10/cinnamon-2-0-released/